# Is my Windows 10 OS gone after I installed Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu from a USB flash drive using [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

I chose the option to keep my Windows 10 OS as well (not pictured in the tutorial).

Now I can't seem to find out how to return to Windows 10. Did I delete my OS?

Comment: @Ray Antebioni The DELL symbol appears and Ubuntu starts up.

Comment: Is it booting to the FlashDrive and do you have more than one hardrive?

Comment: 1. Ubuntu loads whether the flash drive I installed it from is connected to the computer or not. 2. I am unfamiliar with Ubuntu, but when I click "files" in the left-hand menu, the window that opens has a left-hand menu that shows in descending order "Computer || System || Windows || Connect to Server".

Comment: At any point when you turn it on does a pinkish screen appear showing the Ubuntu Installation and the Windows 10?

Comment: When I turn my computer on the DELL screen shows first and then the pink screen shows, followed by the request to sign into Ubuntu. Windows doesn't show as an option; when I start the computer normally or pressing f12 to get boot options.

Comment: OKAY! So Windows 10 drive IS definitely on my computer (files, etc), but I do not know how to boot my laptop in Windows 10. I am thankful the files still exist, at the very least.

Comment: It is possible that it would help if you run the following command to make the grub bootloader aware of Windows: `sudo update-grub` and reboot. It is also possible that the problem depends on how Windows was turned off before you installed Ubuntu. If Windows was hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias fast startup), the file system is not in a state for Ubuntu to read and write to it (definitely not write), and it might not be available, 'seen', and therefore not in the boot menu.

Comment: Try booting Windows via the EFI boot menu (some function key at power-up to allow selection of boot device/OS).  That will skip grub completely, and allow you to shutdown Windows properly.

Comment: @sudodus . That was it! I restarted, updated my windows, which probably caused the issue, then installed Ubuntu via the USB. Thanks so much to all who helped!